# MySQL Increment Insert and Update Column

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a database with following table fields:

```
id   no letter content
1    1         book
2    2         pen
3    3  a      apple
4    3  b      mango
5    3  c      banana
6    4         car
```

I will to insert new value with `id=7, no=2, letter=null and content=moon`.
My question is how will the mysql insert and update command the **"no"**  column so the query result will become: ?

```
no letter content
1         book
2         moon
3         pen
4  a      apple
4  b      mango
4  c      banana
5         car
```

Comment: Let's see the SQL String you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update table 
set no = no + 1 
where no >= 2
and id != 7
```

Comment: Yes you have to update first. If you insert first, there will be 2 rows with no=2. If you can distinguish the 2 rows, you can update after the insert too - just make sure to update the where to exclude the newly inserted row. e.g. add "and id != 7" (updated the answer to reflect this).